# How to see constructors in autocomplete (intellisense) of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

When I want to instantiate a class, and I hit Ctrl+Space, I get the suggestions popup box. It just shows me a list of class names, but no context related suggestions like a list of constructors for that class.  Visual Studio just dumps the 'suggestions' below:

[image]

Can someone help me to make it easier to see what constructors there are, and what parameters a method has?

Comment: When you type the open bracket you actually get a popup with the available overloads usually (you can move to next or previews one with the arrows if more overloads are available). If you don't get overload popup - try check documentation if the actual class does not have a factory method to create an instance.

Comment: In the example case: "To create a SqlDataReader, you must call the ExecuteReader method of the SqlCommand object, instead of directly using a constructor." from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Shift+Space.
Then you should get something like this:
[image]